# NSNumberFormatter not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter, swift5

We trying to do some operation with **Rounding** the values after **X** number of decimals. To do that We are using `NSNumberFormatter` class. The results comes wrong.

Working **JAVA** Code

```
public static double roundOff(double value) {
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");
        df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        return Double.parseDouble(df2.format(value));
    }
    
    public static double roundOff2(double value) {
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        return Double.parseDouble(df2.format(value));
    }
    public static double roundOff2Step(double value) {
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        return Double.parseDouble(df2.format(value));
    }
```

The **Swift** Code We tried.

```
public func convertToRoundValue(number : Double)->Double{
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.roundingMode = .halfEven
    let str = String(describing: formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:number))!)
    return str.toDouble()!
}
```

Is it possible to convert **java** code to **swift**? This calculations are purely based on **Banking Sectors**.

Example values :

**8.60455187289436** to **8.61** In **java** code

**8.60455187289436** to **8.60** In **Swift** code

**My assumption :**

```
//8.60455187289436
//8.60455187289444
//8.6045518728944
//8.604551872894
//8.60455187289
//8.6045518729
//8.604551873
//8.60455187
//8.6045519
//8.604552
//8.60455
//8.6046
//8.605
//8.61
//8.6
```

Thanks to All

Comment: The java code you have posted will never round the value to 8.61, which in my view is correct so both the java and the swift code works correctly

Comment: It does, we are facing issue in calculation because of this..

Comment: Well I tested the code in Visual Studio Code so if you get another result then it is caused by something not explained here. 8.60455187289436 rounded to 2 decimals will yield 8.6 when using `roundOff2` or `roundOff2Step`

Comment: Also if you are building an app for the bank sector and the values represents money then I would suggest using Decimal instead of Double, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) for instance.

Comment: what would be similiar code in Swift to those three methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

1. Don't use number formatters for this conversion. That's very inefficient. Use the `round` or `rounded` functions. And if you want to round to 2 decimal places, you would multiple by 100, round, and then divide by 100.

   E.g., to round a `Double` value to a certain number of decimal places using a banker’s rounding, it would be:

   ```
   extension Double {
       func rounded(to decimalPlaces: Int) -> Double {
           let multiplier = pow(10, Double(decimalPlaces))

           return (self * multiplier).rounded(.toNearestOrEven) / multiplier
       }
   }
   ```

   Thus:

   ```swift
   let value: Double = 8.60455187289436
   let result = value.rounded(to: 2)       // 8.60
   ```
2. The use of banker’s rounding makes me wonder if this is a financial calculation. If so, one should acknowledge problems where many decimal values cannot be represented accurately in floating point types. See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

   My favorite manifestation of this problem is adding 0.1 ten times. With floating point types, this will not work:

   ```swift
   var sum: Double = 0
   let increment: Double = 0.1

   for _ in 0 ..< 10 {
       sum += increment
   }

   if sum != 1 {
       print("This is \(sum)!!!")                // This is 0.9999999999999999!!!
   }
   ```

   You can use `Decimal` to avoid that problem:

   ```swift
   var sum: Decimal = 0
   let increment = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -1, significand: 1)  // or Decimal(string: "0.1")!

   for _ in 0 ..< 10 {
       sum += increment
   }

   if sum == 1 {
       print("Total is 1")
   }
   ```

   Bottom line, if dealing with currency values, you might consider using `Decimal` rather than `Double`.
3. So, if you want to round using `Decimal` you might use:

   ```swift
   extension Decimal {
       func rounded(to decimalPlaces: Int, rounding mode: NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode = .bankers) -> Decimal {
           var input = self
           var result = Decimal()
           NSDecimalRound(&result, &input, decimalPlaces, mode)
           return result
       }
   }
   ```

   And, again:

   ```swift
   let value: Decimal = 8.60455187289436
   let result = value.rounded(to: 2)            // 8.60
   ```
4. You gave the example where `8.60455187289436` was rounded to `8.61` in Java using these routines, using `HALF_EVEN`. I don't believe that’s the case. For example, with:

   ```java
   public double roundOff(double value) {
       DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
       df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
       return Double.parseDouble(df.format(value));
   }
   ```

   I got these results:

   ```java
   double result1 = roundOff(8.60455187289436); // 8.60
   double result2 = roundOff(8.605);            // 8.60
   double result3 = roundOff(8.615);            // 8.62

   Log.d("RoundingDebug", Double.toString(result1) + " " + Double.toString(result2) + " " + Double.toString(result3));
   ```

   If you're getting different results, please show us code. But whether using banker’s rounding or just plain rounding, `8.60455187289436` will never produce `8.61`.
5. All of the discussion presumes that you really need to round the results (e.g. for saving in some data store, the basis for future calculations, etc.). If, however, your intent was simply to show the value to a certain number of decimal places, then a formatter is sufficient. For example, you might define your formatter as a property:

   ```swift
   let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
       let formatter = NumberFormatter()
       formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
       formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
       formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
       formatter.roundingMode = .halfEven
       return formatter
   }()
   ```

   But one would use this formatter solely for the sake of displaying the number as a localized string in the UI to a certain number of decimal places (or for parsing user input). But one would not use this formatter for round-tripping a `Double` to a `String` and back in order to perform rounding. That is an inefficient way of performing rounding calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations  & Decimal approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the same results as you are getting in **Java** use this **ceil** and round up to your requirement.

```
let value = 8.60455187289436
let stringValue = String(format: "%.2f", ceil(value*100)/100)
print(stringValue)
```

[image]

Comment: "the same results as you are getting in Java" but the java code returns 8.6 and not 8.61.

Comment: In his question, he mentioned ```8.60455187289436 to 8.61 In java code``` 
I give the answer according to the question. However, I'll check in Java what is the result.